# Some apps hangs if fstab automount shares not present on boot

Tags: 16.04, fstab, cifs

I'm experiencing a rare issue here.

I have a ubuntu 16.04 server with CIFS working. In my desktop PC I have ubuntu 16.04, and I do automount the server CIFS shares at boot through fstab with this two entries:

```
//server.name/storage /media/storage cifs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0
//server.name/server  /media/server   cifs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```

The issue arises when my server box is down, at that time, if I boot my desktop PC, I think it tryes to mount the CIFS shares somehow and fails, then, some apps start to fail:

- Sometimes Nautilus lags a lot to open
- Gedit lags for about 15 to 20 second to open blank file
- Libreoffice hangs and gets grey screen and unresponsive

If I reboot my desktop PC with that two fstab entries commented, then there are no hangs at all...

I thought that by adding x-systemd.automount I could have that shares on hold until some app calls for it, but it still fails!

Thanks in advise!

Comment: I experience similar problems with `x-systemd.automount`, however with normal `noauto,users` it doesn't get mounted until i click the button in nautilus and thanks to `users` I don't need to enter the password.

Comment: Can you apply that to my fstab entries? so I can see the final result? thanks!

Comment: `//server.name/storage /media/storage cifs noauto,users,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0`
`//server.name/server  /media/server   cifs noauto,users,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0`

Comment: Thanks but sadly, that didn't solved my issue, now I'm getting "mount: only root can mount //server.name/server on /media/server" so I rolled back to my previous config but I get the same result, some apps get hang for a while or just freezes...

Comment: interesting… `users` should prevent that from happening

Comment: Yep, that's a mistery!, just in case, this is the entry that gives me that error //server.name/storage /media/storage cifs noauto,users,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0